# Puppet 4: agent cannot find master due to missing data

Tags: puppet

I'm working from Packt Publishing's "Puppet 4 Essentials: Second Edition" and I'm stuck on page 33. There seems to be a crucial lapse of detail [full excerpt here](https://books.google.com/books?id=dDvlCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=Puppet+first+created+a+new+SSL+certificate+key+for+itself.+For+its+own+name,+it+picked+agent,+which+is+the+machine%27s+hostname.+That%27s+fine+for+now.+An+error+occurred+because+the+puppet+name+cannot+be+currently+resolved+to+anything.+Add+this+to+/etc/hosts+so+that+Puppet+can+contact+the+master:&source=bl&ots=zw7c9FqS7B&sig=ACfU3U0BsjFgDVANCSSIok8atcYL6ySZzQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj6sKu86IDvAhX3FFkFHWM3AQsQ6AEwA3oECAQQAw#v=onepage&q&f=false):

```
Add this to /etc/hosts so that Puppet can contact the master:
```

And it does not specify what to add. I'm new to puppet 4 and currently migrating resources away from it. I'd like to avoid banging my head against the wall here.

Can anyone help me decipher this passage?

EDIT:
I'm trying to run this on Centos 7. The machines can ping each other successfully.

I added this to the agent `/etc/hosts`:

```
10.xxx.xxx.xxx  puppetmaster puppet
```

I added this to the master `/etc/hosts`:

```
10.xxx.xxx.xxx puppetclient agent
```

(confirmed that the IP addresses are correct)

Comment: I'm probably overlooking something basic.

Comment: The problem the book is talking about is that the agent cannot resolve the hostname 'puppet'.  The solution it almost recommends is to add an entry to the agent's `/etc/hosts` for that name.  It looks like that's what you have done, so I guess you figured it out.

Comment: By the way, Puppet 4 is pretty old.  The most recent as I write this is v 7.4, and Puppet, Inc. no longer supports anything earlier than version 5.

Comment: Thanks John!
Well I added that but I'm still not getting the result I want. I guess there is something else going on.
I am using Puppet 4 because legacy reasons in the wild. I have no say in the matter unfortunately.

Comment: What do you have in /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf for `server=....`. With those '/etc/hosts' entries you probably want `server=puppetmaster`.